# Mysql time spent at work by specyfic user

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
+-----+----------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| id  |  user_id |  added_on  | status_enter | status_exit |
+-----+----------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Is it possible to count the time if the data is in other rows?
`12:16:16` - `10:44:1`

```
    User         Date                  Enter    Exit
    -----------  --------------------  ------   ------
    John         2021-06-25 10:44:15   1        0
    John         2021-06-25 12:16:16   0        1
```

Comment: What if both `Enter` and `Exit` are 0 or 1? What if there are 2 rows adjacent by the timestamp with the same `Enter` and `Exit`?

Comment: can you show the example of the result you want to have.

Comment: @Akina  `Enter` is always 1 and Exit is always 1. Always is 1 0 to enter and 0 1 to exit.

Comment: @bigtheo enter time - exit time = e.g 8h

Comment: Well, I can imagine that `CHECK(Enter+Exit=1)` constraint exists. But what about another possible issue?

Comment: @Akina  you mean others users?

Comment: Well, there are ways to do that, what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Dazz Knowles Mysql 5.7.24 and php 7.2.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but SHOULD get what you are looking for.  The outer query is only looking for those where a person clocked IN.  The 3rd column-based select is a correlated query to whatever the current user is and the ID is greater than the check-in, AND it is the check-out.  So its possible a null value here if the person is still clocked-in.  I would have an index on this table by (enter, user, exit, id) to help optimize the query.

```
select
      tc.id,
      tc.user,
      tc.date,
      ( select min( tc2.date )
           from TimeClockTable tc2
           where tc.User = tc2.User
             and tc.id < tc2.id
             and tc2.enter = 0
             and tc2.exit = 1 ) EndTime,
      ( select min( tc2.id )
           from TimeClockTable tc2
           where tc.User = tc2.User
             and tc.id < tc2.id
             and tc2.enter = 0
             and tc2.exit = 1 ) EndTimeID
   from
      TimeClockTable tc

   where
      tc.enter = 1
```

**FEEDBACK**

If the date/time stamp is always going to be sequential with the ID as it is added, ie: ID #1234 on July 5 at 10:00am will ALWAYS be before #1235 on July 5 at 10:01am (you would never have an ID 1235 or higher that was BEFORE the date/time of ID #1234), then the above modification to the query should work for you.  You are already getting the lowest date/time for the given user in comparison to the first, then calling it a second time to get the minimum ID would correlate to the same end time.

Comment: is it still possible to joining the second table?  `INNER JOIN users
ON visitors.user_id = users.enter_code`

Comment: @sagittarius, you could, but that inner query can only return a single value.  What benefit would you get on the extra join but waste resources.  What would be your intention to do that.  If it were to get a filed from visitor, you would need a full copy of the "EndTime" query, but pulling the other visitor information based on that same minimum time requirement, but that is getting very poor.

Comment: One more question, is it possible count this query? I need 'count' for pagination. I think about `select count()`

Comment: @sagittarius, take a look into MySQL Documentation on the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses.  You can probably do that.  OFFSET to handle however ?? * page number displaying, and limit for how many records to show per page.  That should get you going.

Comment: i did so:) `  $sql .= "LIMIT {$per_page} "; $sql .= "OFFSET {$pagination->offset()}";` thanks:)

Comment: One more question, is it possible get `EndTime id`  I need a second id to edit "End Time".

Comment: @sagittarius, see revised answer

Comment: Thank you very much:) Your sql - knowledge is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
SELECT      T.user_id                 AS  User,
            CAST(T.added_on AS DATE)  AS  Date,
            DATEDIFF(
                HOUR, 
                MIN(T.added_on),
                MAX(T.added_on)
            )                         AS  TotalWorkTime

FROM        WorkTable   AS  T
GROUP BY    T.user_id,
            CAST(T.added_on AS DATE)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this assumes that the exit is on the same day as the entry